# jsTree functionality missing when dynamically created

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, web-services, jstree

I have created a jsTree dynamically, the tree is created from a web-service using string builder.

```
 Dim oSB As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
  oSB.Append("<div id='main'>")
   SB.Append("<h4>JSTree</h4>") 
  oSB.Append("<ul id='browser' class='filetree'><li><span class='folder' >Folder         1</span> <ul><li><span class='file'>Item 1.1</span></li></ul></li><li><span c   class='folder'>Folder 2</span> <ul><li><span class='folder'>Subfolder 2.1</span><ul id='folder21'> <li><span class='file'>File 2.1.1</span></li><li><span class='file'>File 2.1.2</span></li></ul></li><li><span class='file'>File 2.2</span></li></ul></li><li class='closed'><span class='folder'>Folder 3 (closed at start)</span><ul><li><span class='file'>File 3.1</span></li>    <li><span class='file'>File 3.2</span></li></ul></li><li><span class='file'>File 4</span></li></ul>")
 oSB.Append("</div>")
```

The Tree is formed but the minimize and max of the nodes are missing, i think it might be the problem with script not loading or something because the same tree in html page works great. I am returning the  tree to the Ajax as

```
 $("div").html(data.d);
```

Can anybody help me out, what am i missing?

Comment: Could you create working jsfiddle? What is actually missing? Are min/max of nodes jsTree attributes?

Comment: Actually i am too new to coding, and stil new to jsfiddle, I do not know how to create it that too with web-service. I am using [link](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) Sample 1. the only change i made was creating the tree from code behind in web-service instead of html, the collapsable and expandable properties are not being applied. I think the js is not attached to this dynamically created tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i got it, i had missed (a simple part)to call the  treeview function after Ajax returns with the value.

```
 function OnLoadSectionSuccess(data) {
            $("#div").html(data.d);
            $("#div").treeview({
                animated: "fast",
                collapsed: true
            });            
    }
```

After i added this the tree is working fine. Anyways thanks for your time.

Cheers